# Is it possible to get a users whole twitter profile in the header user twitter api?

Tags: api, twitter

I am trying to get just the top rectangle (https://twitter.com/cnnbrk see this page to see what I am talking about) from twitter accounts using the twitter api and placing them on my site.  I want users to be able to press follow to follow the user as well.  Anyone know a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite easy. Retrieve the user with the corresponding Twitter API endpoint, i.e. `GET users/show` (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show). Then, do your own rectangle to display the information provided by Twitter.